# "first time" as an adverb meaning "for the first time"

Tags: american-english, adverbs, formality, speech

Can **first time** be used as an adverb meaning "for the first time", e.g.

*when I met him first time* (Confession Tapes, third episode, 02:40)

Comment: Before this question can be answered, you need to show that you have done some research to establish what you can learn about the use of the word.  For example, I can find out that the same question has already been asked (xhttps://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44697/the-first-time-vs-for-the-first-time).  If you look at the one answer to this, you can then say whether you are satisfied, giving your reasons.

Comment: @Tuffy in my question the article is also deleted

Comment: *when I first met him* is standard English and *when I met him first* probably is too

Answer (score 1):

"first-time" works as an adjective but usage as an adverb is quite unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Absent more context it's hard to tell, but "When I met him first time" sounds like unremarkable casual speech.  It's not technically valid syntax (being an elided form of "when I met him *for the* first time"), but it is easily understood and would not shock the listener.